# Match Index Multiple Criteria with Greater Than Issue

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I need the match/index function to only include rows which have a value =>0.
For instance, in the table below I need the formula to list the last 3 results for Chelsea from the bottom but ignoring the rows with blanks.

```
chelsea                3
liverpool              1
chelsea                1
chelsea                2
arsenal                4
manchester utd
chelsea
```

Is there somewhere I can insert a greater than code, such as `AM$4:AM$2000=>0`, or perhaps it needs something to tell it to ignore the blank cells.

Iv been using the code below and it worked fine until I needed to change the structure of the worksheet. Now there's a problem where its picking up blank cells.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(AM$4:AM$2000, LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(AL$4:AL$2000, $B$3, 0)), MATCH(ROW(AL$4:AL$2000), ROW(AL$4:AL$2000)), ""), ROWS(I$15:$I15))),"")
```

So the list of results I end up with should look like

```
Chelsea 2
Chelsea 1
Chelsea 3
```

But instead its including the blank results as 0, and showing

```
Chelsea 0
Chelsea 2
Chelsea 1
```

Help would be gratefully received. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional IF statement to include the second condition of value =>0.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(AM$4:AM$2000, LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(AL$4:AL$2000, $B$3, 0)), IF(AM$4:AM$2000>0,MATCH(ROW(AL$4:AL$2000), ROW(AL$4:AL$2000)), "")), ROWS(I$15:$I15))),"")
```

Comment: a little tweek needed but works perfect, thankyou the time to reply